# finding the root for a windows iis server

Tags: iis, web-server

I'm going into a friend's storefront to upload a javascript display on their computers. They said they have installed Windows IIS, which is because you need a webserver for javascript to read "local" files.

The problem is that I have never used IIS and will need to locate the http://localhost or root directory. Is it usually in C drive? Is windows IIS usually installed in a particular directory?

Comment: "They said they have installed Windows IIS, which is because you need a webserver for javascript to read "local" files" - what?

Comment: javascript cannot read local files

Comment: This is news. Turns out we don't need node.js to run Javascript on the server? Wow.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Usually:

c:\Inetpub\wwwroot

Which version of Windows are you using?  You can verify this location by looking in the IIS manager, but these look different in Windows 2003 vs 2008.

Comment: Thanks, How can I Change it to another drive.?

Answer (score 10):

The default is usually C:\inetpub\wwwroot. If you want to know definitively load up the IIS MMC (Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Internet Information Services) and open up the Sites tab. Find the "Default Web Site" (which is probably the correct one for your purposes) and right click and select Explore. That should open the directory for you. If not, try drilling into Properties.